# Prevent decorator from being used twice on the same function in python

Tags: python, decorator

I have a decorator:

```
from functools import wraps
def d(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        print 'Calling func'
        return f(*args,**kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

And I want to prevent it from decorating the same function twice, e.g prevent things such as:

```
@d
@d
def f():
   print 2
```

Only possible solution I could think of is using a dict to store the functions the decorator has already decorated and raising an exception if asked to decorate a function that exists in the dict.
Do tell if you have a better idea...

Comment: why would anybody write `@d @d def f()`? Shouldn't they be allowed to shoot themselves in the foot if they want to? :-)

Comment: Technically you're right :) But it won't be that simple - If one would make that mistake in half a year, and it will start generating odd results, e.g double printouts etc. they will come to me, and only after a few hours of banging my head against the wall I'll find the problem, probably.

Comment: Nah, you'd ask to see the code, and you'd see the double use fo the decorator directly.

Comment: maybe the place to catch this type of problem is in your unittests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd store the information in the function itself. There is a risk of a conflict if multiple decorators decide to use the same variable, but if it's only your own code, you should be able to avoid it.

```
def d(f):
    if getattr(f, '_decorated_with_d', False):
        raise SomeException('Already decorated')
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        print 'Calling func'
        return f(*args,**kwargs)
    wrapper._decorated_with_d = True
    return wrapper
```

Another option can be this:

```
def d(f):
    decorated_with = getattr(f, '_decorated_with', set())
    if d in decorated_with:
        raise SomeException('Already decorated')
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        print 'Calling func'
        return f(*args,**kwargs)
    decorated_with.add(d)
    wrapper._decorated_with = decorated_with
    return wrapper
```

This assumes that you control all the decorators used. If there is a decorator that doesn't copy the `_decorated_with` attribute, you will not know what is it decorated with.

Comment: I was just thinking that, but i used `hasattr(f,'_decorated_with_d')` It won't work if there is another decorator in bewteen though

Comment: If you control all the decorators, you can use set `_decorated_with`, get it from the `f` function, add `d` to it, and store it back to the new wrapper.

Comment: Well we already know how to detect if there is any wrapper, so combine the two techniques and you can refuse to wrap a decorated function if it has no _decorated_with set on it

Answer (score 2):

I'll also propose my solution:

first, create another decorator:

```
class DecorateOnce(object):
    def __init__(self,f):
        self.__f=f
        self.__called={} #save all functions that have been decorated 
    def __call__(self,toDecorate):
        #get the distinct func name
        funcName=toDecorate.__module__+toDecorate.func_name
        if funcName in self.__called:
            raise Exception('function already decorated by this decorator')
        self.__called[funcName]=1
        print funcName
        return self.__f(toDecorate)
```

Now every decorator you decorate with this decorator, will restrict itself to decorate a func only once:

```
@DecorateOnce
def decorate(f):
    def wrapper...
```

Comment: You can store the function itself (`f`) in `__called`. Using names can always end up being a problem.

Comment: are you sure? I think the function's signature will be different once it's decorated the first time

Comment: Well, by `f` I mean the `self.__f` attribute in `DecorateOnce`, which is the decorator.

Answer (score 0):

Noam, The property of `func_code` to use is `co_name`.  See below, all that is changed is two lines at top of d()'s def

```
def d(f):
   if f.func_code.co_name == 'wrapper':
      return f    #ignore it  (or can throw exception instead...)
   @wraps(f)
   def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
      print 'calling func'
      return f(*args, **kwargs)
   return wrapper
```

Also, see for Lukáš Lalinský's approach which uses a explicitly defined property attached to the function object.  This may be preferable as the "wrapper" name may be used elsewhere...

Answer (score -1):

Look at `f.func_code`, it can tell you if f is a function or a wrapper.

Comment: That's cool, but it will only tell me whether this function has been decorated before or not, but not whether it has been decorated with this specific decorator.

Comment: It will tell you it has been decorated before, but not which decorator