# Avoiding double wrapping in a decorator

Tags: python, decorator

I have a Python 3 script similar to the following:

```
def transaction(write=False):
    def _transaction_deco(fn):
        @wraps(fn)
        def _wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            env.timestamp = arrow.utcnow()
            with TxnManager(write=write) as txn:
                ret = fn(*args, **kwargs)
            delattr(env, 'timestamp')
            return ret
        return _wrapper
    return _transaction_deco

@transaction(True)
def fn1(x=False):
    if x:
        return fn2()
    do_something()

@transaction(True)
def fn2():
    do_something_else()
```

`fn1` and `fn2` can be called independently, and both are wrapped in the `transaction` decorator.

Also, `fn1` can call `fn2` under certain circumstances. This is where I have a problem, because the decorator code is called twice, transactions are nested, and the timestamp is set twice and deleted twice (actually, the second time `delattr(env, 'timestamp')` is called, an exception is raised because `timestamp` is no longer there).

I want whatever is decorated with `transaction` to only be decorated if not already so.

I tried to modify my code based on hints from a [separate Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1547261/3758232):

```
def transaction(write=False):
    def _transaction_deco(fn):
        # Avoid double wrap.
        if getattr(fn, 'in_txn', False):
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)

        @wraps(fn)
        def _wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            # Mark transaction begin timestamp.
            env.timestamp = arrow.utcnow()
            with TxnManager(write=write) as txn:
                ret = fn(*args, **kwargs)
            delattr(env, 'timestamp')
            return ret
        _wrapper.in_txn = True
        return _wrapper

    return _transaction_deco
```

I.e. if the `_in_txn` attribute is set for the function, return the bare function because we are already in a transaction.

However, if I run `fn1(True)` with a debugger, I see that the check for `in_txn` is never true because the `_wrapper` variable is set to `f1` for the outer call, and to `f2` for the inner call, so the functions are being both decorated separately.

I could set the timestamp variables as properties of the context manager, but I still end up with two bested context managers, and if both trnsactions are R/W, Bad Things will happen.

Can someone suggest a better solution?

**Edit:** Based on the replied received, I believe I omitted a key element: `fn1` and `fn2` are API metods and must always run within a transaction. The reason for using a decorator is to prevent the API implementer from having to make a decision about the transaction, or having to wrap the methods manually in a context manager or a decorator. However I would be in favor of a non-decorator approach as long as it keeps the implementation of `fn1` and `fn2` plain.

Comment: Just move `if getattr(fn, 'in_txn', False):` inside the inner wrapper...

Comment: The obvious answer, don't decorate `f1` or `f2`, also has the benefit of making it explicit and obvious when a transaction is in progress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to handle this in the decorator. It's much simpler to separate out the wrapped and unwrapped versions of `fn2`, e.g.:

```
def _fn2():
    do_something_else()

@transaction(True)
def fn1(x=False):
    if x:
        return _fn2()
    do_something()

fn2 = transaction(True)(_fn2)
```

The decorator syntax is just syntactic sugar, so the result will be exactly the same.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than a decorator, I'd just make another context manager to use explicitly.

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def MyTxnManager(write):
    env.timestamp = arrow.utcnow()
    with TxnManager(write=write) as txn:
        yield txn
    delattr(env, 'timestamp')

with MyTxnManager(True) as txn:
    fn1()
```

Here, instead of hiding the transaction inside `fn1` and `fn2`, we wrap just the timestamp management inside a new transaction manager. This way, calls to `fn1` and `fn2` occur in a transaction only if we explicitly cause them to do so.

Comment: This seems like a much more intuitive solution. Would you consider adding the explanation in your comment into the answer? (+1 regardless)

Comment: That is definitely a good solution but won't quite work for me because I want to avoid the method implementer to add the wrapper themselves.

Comment: Code is read far more than it is written; why do you think saving 3 seconds of typing is better than code that is easier to understand?

Comment: It's more about clarity than typing. If I am designing an interface I want to provide all the minimal setup necessary to make it work. If someone tries to implement a method that is required to be wrapped, without wrapping it, their code will break. Why would they have to worry about that?

Answer (score 0):

You can always just check if the environment has a timestamp already and not create it in that case. It is using the already-existing attribute as a flag instead of making a new one:

```
def transaction(write=False):
    def _transaction_deco(fn):
        @wraps(fn)
        def _wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            if hasattr(env, 'timestamp'):
                ret = fn(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                env.timestamp = arrow.utcnow()
                with TxnManager(write=write) as txn:
                    ret = fn(*args, **kwargs)
                delattr(env, 'timestamp')
            return ret
        return _wrapper
    return _transaction_deco
```

This will let you nest an arbitrary number of transacted calls, and only use the timestamp and context manager of the outermost one.