# How to remove offsets in 3D projection plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d, matplotlib-3d

I realized a slight "misalignment" of a plot I'm making in 3D with matplotlib. Here is an MWE:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
figure = plt.figure(figsize=(8,10.7))
ax = plt.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(np.array([[0, 0], [30, 30]]),
                np.array([[10, 10], [10, 10]]),
                np.array([[10, 20], [10, 20]]), 
                rstride=1, cstride=1
)
ax.plot_surface(np.array([[0, 0], [30, 30]]),
                np.array([[20, 20], [20, 20]]),
                np.array([[10, 20], [10, 20]]), 
                rstride=1, cstride=1
)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

Clearly, the bins are not correctly centered, as the surfaces seem to start at 10.5 and end at 20.5 instead of 10 and 20 sharply. How could one achieve the latter?

[image]

**EDIT**: I'm afraid that there is an issue with the suggested answer. The x-axis does not have a solid black line, as is the case by default:

[image]

When I take out the suggested wrapping, I get:

[image]

Unfortunately, when I take out the stuff that I'm plotting, this issue is not reproducible in a Jupyter notebook, but nevertheless, I was wondering about whether you might be able to point out to me what I'd have to do so that in my case, the x-axis has a black line again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by matplotlib's processing of 3D `Axis` coordinates. It deliberately shifts `mins` and `maxs` to create some artificial padding:

> [`axis3d.py#L190-L194`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v3.5.1/lib/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axis3d.py#L190-L194)
>
> ```
> class Axis(maxis.XAxis):
>    ...
>    def _get_coord_info(self, renderer):
>        ...
>        # Add a small offset between min/max point and the edge of the plot
>        deltas = (maxs - mins) / 12
>        mins -= 0.25 * deltas
>        maxs += 0.25 * deltas
>        ...
>        return mins, maxs, centers, deltas, bounds_proj, highs
> ```

As of v3.5.1, there is no parameter to control this behavior.

However, we can use [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) to create a wrapper around `Axis._get_coord_info` that unshifts `mins` and `maxs`. To prevent this wrapper from unshifting multiple times (e.g., when rerunning its Jupyter cell), [track the wrapper state](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1547261/13138364) via an `_unpadded` attribute:

```
from functools import wraps

def unpad(f): # where f will be Axis._get_coord_info
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        mins, maxs, centers, deltas, bounds_proj, highs = f(*args, **kwargs)
        mins += 0.25 * deltas # undo original subtraction
        maxs -= 0.25 * deltas # undo original addition
        return mins, maxs, centers, deltas, bounds_proj, highs

    if getattr(f, '_unpadded', False): # bypass if already unpadded
        return f
    else:
        wrapper._unpadded = True # mark as unpadded
        return wrapper
```

Apply the `unpad` wrapper before plotting:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axis3d import Axis

X = np.array([[0, 0], [30, 30]])
Z = np.array([[10, 20], [10, 20]])
y1, y2, y3 = 10, 16, 20

# wrap Axis._get_coord_info with our unpadded version
Axis._get_coord_info = unpad(Axis._get_coord_info)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 10.7), subplot_kw={'projection': '3d'})
ax.plot_surface(X, np.tile(y1, (2, 2)), Z, rstride=1, cstride=1)
ax.plot_surface(X, np.tile(y2, (2, 2)), Z, rstride=1, cstride=1)
ax.plot_surface(X, np.tile(y3, (2, 2)), Z, rstride=1, cstride=1)

plt.show()
```

[image: unpadded 3d plot]

Comment: When we generally write `*args` and `**kwargs` in the `wrapper` function, as is also done in the Python documentation that you linked, how does Python know what the values for `*args` and `**kwargs` are? After all, `my_decorator` does not return `wrapper(*args, **kwargs)`, but only `wrapper`. Could you please briefly explain this?

Comment: Since python methods are actual objects, `f` / `wrapper` / `Axis._get_coord_info` are all just objects. Here we are assigning the returned method (either `f` or `wrapper`) in place of the `_get_coord_info` method.

Comment: Python won't know what `*args, **kwargs` are until the method gets called (by matplotlib). Using `wrapper(*args, **kwargs)` -> `f(*args, **args)` is just a common pattern for situations like ours where we don't want to change the method signature of `_get_coord_info`, only its internals. Basically we just take whatever the original arguments are and pass them straight through.

Comment: I'm afraid that an issue came up for me with your suggested solution.. Could you please take a look at my edited question?

Comment: I can't reproduce this ([still have axis lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBuPW.png)). Maybe it's a version issue? My `matplotlib.__version__` is 3.5.1.